# How i can get the parent <tr> of an input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following markup as follow:-

```
<tr>
    <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><span class="ms-h3 ms-standardheader" id="IsthisaRegulatoryRequirement">
        <nobr>IsthisaRegulatoryRequirement</nobr>
    </span>
        </td>
    <td valign="top" width="350px" class="ms-formbody">

        <span dir="none"><textarea rows="6" cols="20" id="IsthisaRegulatoryRequirement_91d0fbb4-c10c-4c6a-9490-cc3d540ead9d_$TextField" title="IsthisaRegulatoryRequirement" class="ms-long"></textarea><br></span>     
    </td>
</tr>
```

so based on the textarea id, how I can remove the whole `<tr>` where a textarea with specific id exists?

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/traversing/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Note: 
***In HTML4, ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")***

From the above in HTML4, you can not have `$` in the attribute *id* value.

You can find the [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) *tr* of the element with the *id* specified.

```js
$('#IsthisaRegulatoryRequirement_91d0fbb4-c10c-4c6a-9490-cc3d540ead9d_TextField').closest('tr').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
      <span class="ms-h3 ms-standardheader" id="IsthisaRegulatoryRequirement">
        <nobr>IsthisaRegulatoryRequirement</nobr>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" width="350px" class="ms-formbody">
      <span dir="none">
        <textarea rows="6" cols="20" id="IsthisaRegulatoryRequirement_91d0fbb4-c10c-4c6a-9490-cc3d540ead9d_TextField" title="IsthisaRegulatoryRequirement" class="ms-long"></textarea><br>
      </span>     
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**OR:** You can also use [`.parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)

```
$('#IsthisaRegulatoryRequirement_91d0fbb4-c10c-4c6a-9490-cc3d540ead9d_TextField').parents('tr').remove()
```

Comment: [The bold part is only correct for HTML**4**!](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute)